# Is it possible to make a domain name in the address bar contain upper-case letters?

Tags: apache, url

For example, to make "stackoverflow.com" appear as "StackOverflow.com".

I 1st tried PHP and JS to rewrite the location but only get a reload and the domain rewriting to all lower case.

All I've been able to find so far is about using .htaccess for rewriting file paths that come after the domain, but I've not seen anything about the actual domain yet.

Thanks all.